# spark continuous remove executorid request

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When I launch a spark process I can see in the log a lot of requests to remove the same executor.

For instance, when a executor is correctly removed I can see this log:

```
23/08/18 10:56:27 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 2
23/08/18 10:56:27 INFO cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 2
23/08/18 10:56:27 INFO cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: Actual list of executor(s) to be killed is 1
23/08/18 10:56:27 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster$AMEndpoint: Driver requested to kill executor(s) 2.
```

Then in the executors tab I can see that executor 2 is dead

But other times the executor doesn't seem to be removed and is always trying to remove it:

```
23/08/17 11:32:53 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 6
23/08/17 11:32:53 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 6
23/08/17 11:32:53 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 6
23/08/17 11:32:53 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 6
23/08/17 11:32:53 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 6
23/08/17 11:32:53 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 6
.....
```

In the executors tab the executor 6 is always active

I think this isn't a normal situation but I can't see any errors in the logs.

Does anyone know why this happens?

thanks in advance